# can not upload file to child model within parent form ruby on rails with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have been stuck for 2 days trying to figure out how to upload a file with carrierwave to a model and have that model attached to a parent.

```
class HandOut < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_post
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
end

class HandOutsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @handOut = HandOut.new
  end

  def create
    @handOut = HandOut.new(hand_out_params)
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def hand_out_params
    params.require(:hand_out).permit(:attachment)
  end
end
```

This is the create for the parent

```
def create
    @c = Course.find_by_id(params[:course_id])
    @coursePost = @c.course_posts.build(post_params)
    @coursePost.hand_outs.build(params[:attachment])
    if (@coursePost.save)
      redirect_to controller: 'courses', action: 'show', id: params[:course_id]
    end
  end
def post_params
    params.require(:course_post).permit( :course_id, :title, :content)
  end
```

And this is the form

```
<%= form_for(@newPost, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, @course.id) %>
    <div class= "field">
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class= "field">
      <%= f.text_field :content %>
    </div>
    <div class= "field">
      <%= f.file_field(:attachment) %>
    </div>
    <div class= "actions">
      <%= f.submit "Post!" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Also the coursePost is created inside the show of the courses(parent to course post)

```
def show
    @posts = @course.course_posts.all
    @newPost = CoursePost.new
  end
```

This is the coursePost model

```
class CoursePost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :hand_outs
  validates :course_id, presence: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Thank you appreciate the help.

Comment: can you post the `CoursePost` model?

Answer (score 0):

Add [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to CoursePost:

```
has_many :hand_outs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :hand_outs
validates :course_id, presence: true
```

And [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) in the newPost form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :hand_outs do |h| %>
  <div class= "field">
    <%= h.file_field :attachment %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Update the `post_params` to:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:course_post).permit(:course_id, :title, :content, hand_outs_attributes: [:attachment])
end
```

And now remove the line in create method:

```
@coursePost.hand_outs.build(params[:attachment])
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but now the file_field doesn't show up.

Comment: I fixed that issue by removing the f. but now it doesn't even seem to create a handout object